# Power BI Rest API - Upload datatable with more than 75 columns

Tags: c#, rest, datatable, powerbi

Is it possible to upload and populate a PBI datatable with more than 75 columns with Power BI Rest API?

This article is mentioning just posting rows...
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn950053.aspx

Is there any other handy way how to upload a datatable with 75+ columns programmatically?

Thank you thousand times
Martin

Comment: Are you trying to upload a datatable or load a dashboard?  The issue with a dashboard is you are limited to the number of controls that will fit in a windows.

Comment: I am trying to upload a datatable with more than 75 columns..